# Zero subscheme and zero locus

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

On [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/089X) page on StacksProject about coherent sheaves on projective spaces they define a hypersurface to be the zero scheme $Z(s)$ of a global section $ s \in \Gamma(\mathbb{P}_k^n,\mathcal{O}(d))$, which is defined [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02OQ). I know that those global sections can be identified with homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $k[X_0, \ldots, X_n]$, so let $f_d$ be the homogeneous polynomial corresponding to $s$. My question is, does this zero scheme coincide with the closed subscheme $V_{+}(f_d)=Proj(k[X_0, \ldots,X_n]/(f_d)) $? This would make sense since this last scheme is sometimes called "zero locus", but I am not able to show this from the abstract definition of $Z(s)$ in stacks project.

I know that $Z(s)$ is, by definition, a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}_k^n$, so it must be of the form $Proj(k[X_0, \ldots, X_n]/I)$ for some homogeneous ideal $I$, but I do not know how to show $I=(f_d)$.

EDIT: In fact, the case $d=1$ is showed [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/089Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think can be seen by just using the standard cover of projective space: if $\text{Spec}\left(k\left[\frac{X_0}{X_i},\ldots,\frac{X_n}{X_i}\right]\right) \cong U_i = D(X_i) \subset \mathbf{P}^n_k$ then $$
U_i \cap V(s) = V(s_{\mid D(X_i)}) \cong \text{Spec}\left(k\left[\frac{X_0}{X_i},\ldots,\frac{X_n}{X_i}\right]/f_d\left(\frac{X_0}{X_i},\ldots,\frac{X_n}{X_i}\right)\right) $$
which agrees with the standard affine cover of $\text{Proj}(k[X_0,\ldots,X_n]/f_d)$, and the gluing isomorphisms on the intersections of course also agrees.

It wish I could say this follows by some abstract principle but, disenchantingly, the Proj construction really fails at functoriality...

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer :). If I am not wrong, there you have proved that $V(f_d) \cong Spec(k[X_0, \ldots, X_n]/(f_d))$, right? What I was asking is to show that this is the same as the "zero subscheme" $Z(s)$ defined in the link I provided to stacksproject.

Comment: Hey! My pleasure:D what I showed is that when you intersect $Z(s)$ with any of the standard affine opens $D(X_i)\subset \mathbf{P}^n_k$ you get an affine scheme isomorphic to the standard open $D(T_i) \subset \text{Proj}\,k[T_0,\ldots,T_n]/f_d$. If the gluing data on the intersections $D(X_iX_j)$ also agrees, then these two schemes are isomorphic. Hope this helps :P

Comment: My problem is: how did you deduce from the definition of $Z(s)$ I provided that:

$U_i \cap V(s) = V(s_{|D(X_i)}) \cong Spec(...)$

  (when you write $V(s)$ I suppose you mean $Z(s)$).

Comment: Ahhh right! It depends on what definition for $Z(s)$ you use; this equality follows from the following construction: if $X$ is a scheme and $s \in\Gamma(X,\mathcal{E})$ is a global section of some quasi coherent sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on $X$, then $s$ corresponds to a morphism $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{E}$ which induces $\mathcal{E}^\vee\to\mathcal{O}_X^\vee\cong\mathcal{O}_X$ whose image is a quasi-coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{O}_X$. The corresponding closed subscheme is your $Z(s)$ and all these operations commute with $(-)_{\mid U}$ for any open $U\subseteq X$.

Comment: Yes! So writing things more explicitly for this case: The map $\mathcal{O}(d)^{\vee} = Hom_{\mathcal{O}}(\mathcal{O}(d), \mathcal{O} ) \rightarrow \mathcal{O} $ is given by "evaluation on $s$", right? Then, I suppose that the image of this is just the "ideal sheaf generated by $s$", which is what I do not understand very well, and then your claim follows. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Exactly! for instance, if you have an affine scheme $\text{Spec}\,A$ and you just take $\mathcal{E}=\widetilde{A}\oplus \widetilde{A}, s=(s_1, s_2)\in A\oplus A$ an arbitrary element, then the dual of the map $A \xrightarrow{\cdot (s_1,s_2)} A\oplus A$ is $A\oplus A \to A$ given by $(a_1,a_2)\mapsto a_1s_1 + a_2s_2$ whose image is precisely the ideal generated by $s_1,s_2$ :D

Comment: Yay! Thank you very much Thomas :D